# Putting an Image Inside Kendo UI Tooltip in Angular Material

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, angular-material, kendo-ui-angular2

I am looking for a good example on how to put an image inside a tooltip using Kendo and Angular Material, but cannot find one. All the examples I see refer to putting in text or links, none deal with adding in images or other custom content. Any idea or clear examples on how to do so?

```
    <ng-template #template let-anchor>
        {{ anchor.nativeElement.getAttribute("img") }}
    </ng-template>

    <div kendoTooltip
         [tooltipTemplate]="template" >
        <button mat-raised->
            <a> <img [src]="imgSrc" alt="Tool Tip Help Image."> </a>
            button text
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you have a link inside your button? What do you think happens on click?